# How do you figure the solar diffuse proportion and transmissivity value from data?

Tags: gis, arcgis

The data can be found here:

http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/bluebook/data/24283.SBF

How do I figure the solar diffuse proportion and the transmissivity value from what's there?

Anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might start by reading the documentation for the data format...and this may lead to some textbooks or papers that you need to know...

If these types of resources are not available, try to learn the name of the author and send them an email (or even give them call). Be polite, and be prepared to explain who you are, and why you want to do this...

Just about the only alternative, is to find an existing code (perhaps in language you can't *run*, but can *read*) and copy the approach taken therein.

Welcome to the wonderful world of scientific data archeology.